# How do they shoot flaming human scenes?

Tags: film-techniques, stunts

This scene was found in [*Billy Madison* (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112508/).

[image]

How do they shoot dangerous stunt scenes?

Comment: If you went to Studios park at Disneyland Paris when "Moteurs, Action!" stunt show was running they did this several times a day in front of a live audience ([youtube from someone with a good seat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJonQ0wPz68)) with no CGI.  It's surprising just how long they let the stuntperson burn.

Comment: As a film student before CGI and even video, I needed a shot for a short film where a guy was screaming with his head on fire.  I took a shot of him screaming, and a separate shot of a wad of newspaper on fire in front of a black background. I projected both on the same screen at the same time, lining up the flaming ball over his screaming head, and filmed that. The resulting shot -- less than one second long -- looked surprisingly convincing. (That's not how stunt people manage this effect. I just wanted to mention this anecdote.)

Comment: _How do they shoot dangerous stunt scenes?_ Quickly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The stuntman/stuntwoman wears a special flame-retardant suit under their costume.  In addition, any skin which is not covered by the suit gets coated with a special gel which is flame-resistant.  Additionally, there are a few people with fire extinguishers in hand who jump in immediately after the director cuts the scene to extinguish the flames.

Comment: I love that they have a flamethrower in that first video

Answer (score 27):

For that movie it was probably using a [pyro gel](http://www.rogergeorge.com/special-effects/expendables/pyro-gel). It's a special gel that burns at a lower temperature (800F) and doesn't spread much, so it can be applied more precisely. To protect themselves the actors use a combination of a Stunt Gel (acts as a temperature isolation) and fire resistant clothes.

That said, it's a high risk stunt and not for amateurs. The safer way would be to use CGI to add the flames digitally later, although possibly won't look as convincing as real flames.